# Dialogflow html/js card json value v1

Tags: javascript, html, json, dialogflow-es

I am trying to access the card json value, to no avail.

In my scenario, I am asking the bot about "weather in London" and it replies back with "It is currently 9 degrees celcius in London." via the webhook.

Which is correct and dynamic.

However, I am trying to also pass the values to a card too.

In the json reply, I do get the card as so

```
{
  "id": "REMOVED",
  "timestamp": "2017-12-05T11:10:52.033Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "weather in london",
    "action": "sayWeather",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "geo-city": "London"
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "REMOVED",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 626,
      "intentName": "Weather"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "It is currently 9 degrees celcius in London.",
      "source": "agent",
      "displayText": "It is currently 9 degrees celcius in London.",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "It is currently 9 degrees celcius in London."
        }
      ],
      "data": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "This is the first simple response for a basic card"
            }
          },
          {
            "basicCard": {
              "title": "Title: this is a title",
              "formattedText": "This is a basic card.  Text in a\n      basic card can include \"quotes\" and most other unicode characters\n      including emoji .  Basic cards also support some markdown\n      formatting like *emphasis* or _italics_, **strong** or __bold__,\n      and ***bold itallic*** or ___strong emphasis___ as well as other things\n      like line  \nbreaks",
              "subtitle": "This is a subtitle",
              "image": {
                "url": "https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png",
                "accessibilityText": "Image alternate text"
              },
              "buttons": [
                {
                  "title": "This is a button",
                  "openUrlAction": {
                    "url": "https://assistant.google.com/"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "This is the 2nd simple response ",
              "displayText": "This is the 2nd simple response"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },

  "sessionId": "REMOVED"
}
```

Accessing the value of speech using `data.result.fulfillment.speech` works fine.

However, when using `data.result.fulfillment.data.items.basicCard.image.url` it just doesnt work. And if I go up several levels, I do get:

> [object Object]

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `items` attribute is a list and not an object.  As such, you'll have to use a numerical index to retrive the data.  In the example you provided the index of the `basicCard` object is second so your code should look something like this:

`data.result.fulfillment.data.items[1].basicCard.image.url`

Notice the `[1]` after `items`.

Bear in mind that if the order of this list changes you may no longer be retrieving a `basicCard` object so you may want to add some checking to make sure you're retrieving the data you want.

Comment: Lack of sleep i guess. Sorry for my stupidity, completely lost it. Hhhhh. Thanks!

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help. I make mistakes like this all the time.